# The best way to pass SDF objects between forms

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I want to find a best way to pass objects from a SQL Server CE database in my desktop Winforms application in order to decrease memory usage.

I have a `.sdf` local database connected to the project by generated dbml.

Also I have 4 forms:

1. `MainForm` - One main parent form with button to select Product object.
2. `ProductSelectForm` - Form to select Product from database.
3. `MainProductForm` - MDI children forms that displays information and charts about selected Product and button to edit this information.
4. `ProductForm` - Form that can add new Product or edit information about selected Product.

I see two options: either to pass id of items or to pass Item object.

Basing on example below, what would be best ways to pass information between forms: by id or by object?

Maybe other recommendations?

Main Form:

```
public MainForm() 
{
     InitializeComponent(); 
}

private void ProductSelectBarButton_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
        ProductSelectForm PSF = new ProductSelectForm();

        if (PSF.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
                MainProductForm MPF = new MainProductForm(PSF.ProductSelected);
                MPF.MdiParent = this;
                MPF.Show();
        }

        PSF.Dispose();
}
```

ProductSelectForm:

```
public Product ProductSelected = null;      

public ProductSelectForm() { InitializeComponent(); }

private void OKButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var ActiveItem = ProductGrid.GetFocusedRowCellValue("Product_ID");
        ProductSelected = DB.Product.Where(x => x.Product_ID == (int)ActiveItem).Single();
        this.Close();                
}
```

MainProductForm:

```
public Product cProduct;        

public MainProductForm(Product product) {
        InitializeComponent();
        cProduct = product;
        this.Text = cProduct.Product_Name;
}

private void ProductEditBarButton_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
        ProductForm PF = new ProductForm(EditMode.Edit, cProduct.Product_ID);
        PF.ShowDialog();
        PF.Dispose();
        Form_Refresh();
}
```

ProductForm:

```
private Product T = null;
private EditMode Mode;
public Product ProductAdded = null;

public ProductForm(EditMode mode) : this(mode, 0) { }

public ProductForm(EditMode mode, int ID)
{
        InitializeComponent();
        Mode = mode;          
        switch (Mode)
        {
            case (EditMode.Add):
                T = new Product();
                break;

            case (EditMode.Edit):
                T = CurrentState.cDB.Product.Where(x => x.Product_ID == ID).Single();
                NameEdit.Text = T.Product_Name;
                break;
        }            
}

private void OKButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            T.Product_Name = NameEdit.Text;
            if (Mode == EditMode.Add)
            {
                DB.Product.InsertOnSubmit(T);
            }
            DB.SubmitChanges();
            if (Mode == EditMode.Add) 
                ProductAdded = DB.Product.Where(x => x.Product_ID == T.Product_ID).Single();
            this.Close();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass by ID, each form has to re-select the data from the database. That's a lot of work, both for the PC *and* for the developer. Your product likely has a completely negligible memory footprint. So if you aren't programming for a memory-challenged system (and today that would mean half-a-phone or broken-calculator or something) then by all means create a system that uses a bit more memory in favor of less battery usage and less errors due to the developer not needing to reinvent the wheel in every form.

Comment: If I select object in ProductSelectForm (public Product ProductSelected), pass it to MainForm (new MainProductForm(PSF.ProductSelected)) and open it in ProductForm (public Product cProduct;) - does this mean that I use memory 3 time more?

Comment: Or ProductSelected is the same as cProduct and uses one memory slot?

Comment: Depends on many factors. If it's a reference type (class) then the memory is only occupied once while a reference is passed along to all forms. But even if you do use 3 times the memory. How much memory are we talking about?